# Script to submit the button and then refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to run a script on button, it will first submit the data and then refresh the page. Bewlo is the script I am using but it is only refreshing the page but not submitting the data.

```
<button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" onClick="window.location.reload();" value="<? 
php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce');? 
> 
<script>
const reloadtButton = document.querySelector("#reload");
// Reload everything:
function reload() {
reload = location.reload();
}
// Event listeners for reload
reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reload, false);
</script></button>
```

Comment: Please someone help in the same

Comment: You button does not have an id called reload

Comment: Hi  Carsten Løvbo Andersen, thanks for your reply, can you please make changes in the code and update. Thanks in advance

Comment: @RajivGanger can you share more info on where this button is located. If it is inside a form, you don't need to add `onclick` (not `onClick`) to your button or handle the reload if the form submits to the same page. 

If it is somewhere else, then you will have to either use javascript to post the data to some end point at the server or some other library like jquery to do that and then do the reload as you have done in the `reload` function

Comment: Hi Shivaramanaiyer, This button is of cart page (update cart).

Comment: You don't need any JS for this. The default behaviour of submitting an HTML `<form>` is to reload the page. For that matter, most of the time, devs try to _prevent_ this default behaviour because it's annoying. You're trying to do the exact opposite, emulate a reload on submit with JS :)

Comment: Yes I understand that but whenever we are clicking on button to update the cart then Cart titel is disappearing, so when I refresh the page it comes back. I don't know why it is happening.